# document.getElementsByTagName("svg_text") is not working

Tags: javascript, svg

```
document.createSvg = function(tagName) {
   var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
   return this.createElementNS(svgNS, tagName);
};

var svgPie = document.createSvg("svg");
metric_name = document.createSvg("g");


text_metric = document.createSvg("text");
text_metric.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i]['name']));
text_metric.setAttribute("name",data[i]['name']);
text_metric.setAttribute("text-anchor","start");
text_metric.setAttribute("font-size","13");
text_metric.setAttribute("id", data[i]['id']);

resetList =  document.getElementsByTagName("text");

alert(resetList[0]); 

metric_name.appendChild(text_metric);
svgPie.appendChild(metric_name);
```

Above alert is giving me undefined. Can you give the reason and solution to resolve it

Comment: Well, in Chromium 24 (Ubuntu 12.10), I'm getting: [`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'createSVG'`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3r6FQ/) This may be important, and probably worth checking for errors in your own JavaScript console. Incidentally, using `createSvg` (as in your own code) generates the same error ([albeit with different casing, obviously](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3r6FQ/1/)).

Comment: `document.createSVG(...)` is not a built-in function, does `alert(text_metric)` returns what you expect?

Comment: @Chirag: please add that code to your *question*, code is (almost entirely) unreadable in comments. Can you reproduce your problem ([minimal/SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) in a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Duopixel: I know it is not built in...everything is working...What I am doing is that I have multiple svg text and I setting there stroke as black when user click on it...I have multiple svg text...when user click on another svg text then stroke of all other svg text should be set to none

Comment: @DavidThomas: I have added the code I believe it will give the proper picture

Answer (score 2):

You are executing `document.getElementsByTagName('text')` without ever appending the SVG to the DOM, so the result is always empty.

You can do...

```
document.body.appendChild(svgPie);
resetList =  document.getElementsByTagName("text");
alert(resetList[0]);
```

And it will work.